# How to get HTML file as a content to mail (shell script)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, script

I am new to shell script, I have an HTML file which contains table data. Now I need to send this file to mail.

```
mail -s "test" abc.com <test.html
```

Currently I am getting the raw HTML code for the table in mail.

I need the table content in mail  as we get in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Question previously answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591755/how-send-html-mail-using-linux-command-line http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317174/sending-html-mail-using-a-shell-script

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `-a "Content-type: text/html;"` to the message like this:

```
mail -a "Content-type: text/html;" -s "test" abc.com <test.html
```

You can easily test this by running this command that `echo`’s simple HTML to the `mail` command:

```
echo "<html><b>Test</b></html>" | mail -a "Content-type: text/html;" -s "test" abc.com
```

Got this idea from [this question and answer thread on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/15405) as well as [this similar thread on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2591755/117259).

Answer (score 1):

If you need the html sent as attachment, then you can use the shell tool called mpack.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/mpack

EDIT FOR SAMPLE:

I as a simple user send a dummy mail to root with /etc/hosts attached:

```
$ mpack -s 'trx of /etc/hosts' /etc/hosts root@localhost
```

and as root, I'm checking my box:

```
# mail
Mail version 8.1.2 01/15/2001.  Type ? for help.
"/var/mail/root": 1 message 1 new
& p
Message 1:
From sgombai@localhost  Thu Feb 11 01:54:27 2016
Date: Thu, 11 Feb 2016 01:54:27 +0100
From: sgombai <sgombai@localhost>
Mime-Version: 1.0
To: root@localhost
Subject: trx of /etc/hosts
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="-"

This is a MIME encoded message.  Decode it with "munpack"
or any other MIME reading software.  Mpack/munpack is available
via anonymous FTP in ftp.andrew.cmu.edu:pub/mpack/
---
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="hosts"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="hosts"
Content-MD5: 9WRRh8Yr7YPb7zo1AsgwcA==

MTI3LjAuMC4xCWxvY2FsaG9zdAo5LjE1Ny4yMTQuMTc4CXZhY21mcy52YWMuaHUuaWJtLmNv
bQl2YWNtZnMKCiMgVGhlIGZvbGxvd2luZyBsaW5lcyBhcmUgZGVzaXJhYmxlIGZvciBJUHY2
IGNhcGFibGUgaG9zdHMKOjoxICAgICBsb2NhbGhvc3QgaXA2LWxvY2FsaG9zdCBpcDYtbG9v
cGJhY2sKZmUwMDo6MCBpcDYtbG9jYWxuZXQKZmYwMDo6MCBpcDYtbWNhc3RwcmVmaXgKZmYw
Mjo6MSBpcDYtYWxsbm9kZXMKZmYwMjo6MiBpcDYtYWxscm91dGVycwpmZjAyOjozIGlwNi1h
bGxob3N0cwo=

-----
```

So it's arrived with attachment ready to be saved/decoded by any modern mailing program.

Comment: Can you include a little more information as links are not typically acceptable as answers? Even just outlining what it is, what its prereqs are, etc. go a long way.